For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, does there exist square matrices $A,B,C\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ satisfying
For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, does there exist square matrices $A,B,C\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ satisfying
$A^{2k+1}=I,B^{2k+1}=I, C^{2k+1}=I$ and also $A+B=C$. Here $I$ is the identity matrix.
We can choose $A$ to be the companion matrix of the polynomial $x^{2k+1}-1$. But how to construct $B,C$

Are you asking if such matrices exist for any given $k$, or are you asking whether there is some $k$ for which such matrices exist?  (for what little it matters, I think the same answer applies to both, but the former is easily answered for $k=0$)

I don't think the OP considers $0$ to be a natural number.(neither do i) @BrianMoehring

I am considering the set $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of all integers ${0,\pm 1,\pm2,\pm3,\ldots}$

@Brian Moehring, yeah I am asking for any given $k$, that is,  $k$ can be $1,2,3,4,\ldots$. $A$ is a square matrix.
